# After exiting from ssh connection, process is killed/times out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, python, nohup

I'm running a python script in the background on an Ubuntu ssh server. `nohup python x.py &`
After a certain amount of time, maybe half an hour, the python script stops running when I come back into the server and type ps. Not sure why. I don't want it to ever time out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes in an SSH session belong to your shell's process; typically:
`sshd [your-username] tty[your-tty]`.

When you kill your session, all child processes are also exited.

To get around this, use terminal multiplexing, or daemons.

The most common multiplexers are [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

You would then start screen by using the `screen -S my-session-name`, and running your process normally.

You can then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from the screen, and the process will still be running, but *as a child of screen, not your ssh session*

To reattach, type `screen -x my-session-name` (-r also works)

Comment: So why doesn't screen die for the same reason the python script does?

Comment: Getting a memory error now, program doesnt run as far as it did before

Comment: @MattiasÅslund screen creates another TTY in /tmp (a socket, really), that will have processes belonging to it, rather than using your current TTY (which will be in `/dev/tty[id]`), since that will go poof when sshd decides it's time to exit. you call screen; it's not invoked by your shell

Comment: @Anonymous are you sure you weren't running into swap space previously?

Comment: I think so. Before I loaded data and processed it for some time and I guess when I exited, the process stopped. Now the program throws a memory error when loading the data, doesn't even get to the processing.

Comment: I tried it on a 64 bit server, worked. Weird though, worked on the 32 bit before. Thank you.